# How can I show the right answer if the answer is wrong android?

Tags: java, android

In **CheckAns** it cheek if the answer coming from the data or the web api is correct so I want to if the answer is not correct to show the right answer.

So the idea here to after answer the question it will show the level dialog the current point level so I want to show the right answer if it wrong 
when the answer is right the app continue to the next question but if it wrong the app show the current point dialog.

[image]

---

```
package com.app.trafficexam;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.db.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.item.ItemStage;
import com.example.util.Constant;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlayQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web_desc;
    private long timeCountInMilliSeconds = (long) (0.50 * 60000);

    private enum TimerStatus {
        STARTED,
        STOPPED
    }

    private TimerStatus timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
    private ProgressBar progressBarCircle;
    private TextView textViewTime, txt_pointshow;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Button btnopta, btnoptb, btnoptc, btnoptd;
    String str_a, str_b, str_c, str_d, ansright;
    private int currentPosition;
    int TOTAL_TEXT, points, time;
    ArrayList<ItemStage> mListItem;
    boolean isTimerOn;
    long millisTimerRemains;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playquiz_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mListItem = new ArrayList<>();
        web_desc = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.text_question);
        progressBarCircle = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarCircle);
        textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        txt_pointshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_point);
        btnopta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_optionA);
        btnoptb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_optionB);
        btnoptc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_optionC);
        btnoptd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_optionD);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        web_desc.setBackgroundColor(0);
        web_desc.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        web_desc.setFocusable(false);
        web_desc.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
        web_desc.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);
        isTimerOn = false;

        Intent i = getIntent();
        currentPosition = i.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);

        TOTAL_TEXT = Constant.arrayList.size() - 1;

        setQuestionView(currentPosition);

        btnopta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                str_a = Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesOptA();
                CheckAns();

            }
        });

        btnoptb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                str_b = Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesOptB();
                CheckAns();

            }
        });

        btnoptc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                str_c = Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesOptC();
                CheckAns();

            }
        });

        btnoptd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                str_d = Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesOptD();
                CheckAns();

            }
        });
    }

    public void CheckAns() {
        ansright = Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesAns();
        if (ansright.equals(str_a)) {
            isAnswerTrue();
            startStop();
        } else if (ansright.equals(str_b)) {
            isAnswerTrue();
            startStop();
        } else if (ansright.equals(str_c)) {
            isAnswerTrue();
            startStop();
        } else if (ansright.equals(str_d)) {
            isAnswerTrue();
            startStop();
        } else {
            Intent intentres = new Intent(PlayQuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intentres.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentres);
            stopCountDownTimer();
        }
    }

    private void isAnswerTrue() {

        if (currentPosition <= TOTAL_TEXT) {

            time = (int) millisTimerRemains;
            int point = PointCount(time);

            if (!databaseHelper.getFavouriteById(Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesId())) {
                ContentValues fav = new ContentValues();
                fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_LEVEL_ID, Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesLevelId());
                fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STAGE_ID, Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesId());
                fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TOTAL_POINT, point);
                databaseHelper.addFavourite(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_FAVOURITE_NAME, fav, null);
            }
            if (currentPosition < TOTAL_TEXT) {
                if (!databaseHelper.getFavouriteById(Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesId())) {
                    ContentValues fav = new ContentValues();
                    fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_LEVEL_ID, Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesLevelId());
                    fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_STAGE_ID, Constant.arrayList.get(currentPosition).getLevelWiseQuesId());
                    fav.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TOTAL_POINT, point);
                    databaseHelper.addFavourite(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_FAVOURITE_NAME, fav, null);
                }
                setQuestionView(currentPosition + 1);
            }
            else{
                Intent intentres = new Intent(PlayQuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                intentres.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intentres);
                stopCountDownTimer();
            }

        } else {
            Intent intentres = new Intent(PlayQuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intentres.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intentres);
            stopCountDownTimer();
        }
    }

    private void setQuestionView(int positionToMoveTo) {
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = Constant.arrayList.get(positionToMoveTo).getLevelWiseQuesQuestion();

        String text = "<html><head>"
                + "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/custom.ttf\")}body{font-family: MyFont;color: #ffffff;text-align:justify}"
                + "</style></head>"
                + "<body>"
                + htmlText
                + "</body></html>";

        web_desc.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
        btnopta.setText(Constant.arrayList.get(positionToMoveTo).getLevelWiseQuesOptA());
        btnoptb.setText(Constant.arrayList.get(positionToMoveTo).getLevelWiseQuesOptB());
        btnoptc.setText(Constant.arrayList.get(positionToMoveTo).getLevelWiseQuesOptC());
        btnoptd.setText(Constant.arrayList.get(positionToMoveTo).getLevelWiseQuesOptD());
        currentPosition = positionToMoveTo;
        startStop();

    }

    public int PointCount(int timeremain) {
        if (timeremain < 29 && timeremain >= 25) {
            points = 5;
            txt_pointshow.setText("" + points);
        } else if (timeremain < 25 && timeremain >= 20) {
            points = 3;
            txt_pointshow.setText("" + points);
        } else if (timeremain < 20 && timeremain >= 1) {
            points = 1;
            txt_pointshow.setText("" + points);
        }

        return points;
    }

    private void startStop() {
        if (timerStatus == TimerStatus.STOPPED) {
            setProgressBarValues();
            timerStatus = TimerStatus.STARTED;
            startCountDownTimer();

        } else {

            timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
            stopCountDownTimer();

        }
    }

    private void startCountDownTimer() {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMilliSeconds, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {

                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished));
                progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                millisTimerRemains = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
                setProgressBarValues();
                timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
                //finish();
                Intent intentres = new Intent(PlayQuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                intentres.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intentres);

            }

        }.start();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void stopCountDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    private void setProgressBarValues() {

        progressBarCircle.setMax((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
        progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
    }

    private String hmsTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {
        String hms = String.format("%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds)));

        return hms;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopCountDownTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that if the user taps the button with the wrong answer, just change the background color of the button with the correct answer to green, and the wrong one with red, then have a text view that show the selected answer and the correct answer, and if the user selected the correct answer, then just display the next question:

[sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3xJZ.png)

**UPDATE:**

OK I created a simple example of what I'm talking about.

First, you have to create three drawables (in res->drawable) that will be the background of button:

- button.xml -> grey (default background)
- background button_wrong.xml -> read background
- button_correct.xml -> green background

***button.xml***

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#807676"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#BCBCBC" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#807676" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#BCBCBC" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

***button_wrong.xml***

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#f46767"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#ff4040" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#86ff4040" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#ff4040" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

***button_correct.xml***

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#67f47c"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#40FF5D" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#8640ff5d" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#40FF5D" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Second, use the drawable (button.xml) on your layout as the default button background:

***activity_main.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context="ph.codehood.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="-- Result will appear here --"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="SELECTION ITEM" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="SELECTION ITEM" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="SELECTION ITEM" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="SELECTION ITEM" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then last, implement the code:

***MainActivity.java***

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String correctAnswer = "C"; // <= Define the correct answer A, B, C, or D
    Button correctButton;
    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        // Define which button has the correct answer
        switch (correctAnswer) {
            case "A":
                correctButton = btn1;
                break;
            case "B":
                correctButton = btn2;
                break;
            case "C":
                correctButton = btn3;
                break;
            case "D":
                correctButton = btn4;
                break;
        }

        correctButton.setText("CORRECT ANSWER");

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer("A", v);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer("B", v);
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer("C", v);
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer("D", v);
            }
        });

    }

    void checkAnswer(String selectionLetter, View v) {

        // change background of correct answer to green
        correctButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_correct);

        if (selectionLetter.equals(correctAnswer)) {
            textView1.setText("-- Correct Answer, Proceed to next question -- ");
        } else {
            // change background of correct answer to red
            textView1.setText("WRONG ANSWER\nCORRECT IS: " + correctAnswer + "\nSELECTED: " + selectionLetter);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_wrong);
        }

        resetBackgrounds(v);
    }

    void resetBackgrounds(final View v) {
        // Reset everything after 1.5 sec
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView1.setText("-- Result will appear here --");
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
                correctButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            }
        };

        Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500);
    }
}
```

Test this code on a separate Android Studio project to see the output.

[image]

Comment: can you be more clearly i know what u mean but how can i do it in me code or can u give me your code so i can understand how it is work

Comment: good that was a good example :) but this is my project can you make it on my  https://www.mediafire.com/file/y8crkz7aj6kemy3/traffic.rar   so can u do u in my project

Comment: I'm sorry but I should not do the code for you. I already provided an example, :).

Comment: i don't get the hole thing so i'm still student and this is my graduation project i try it like u did but it does not work with me so this is my full project just notes to me where i show change it

Comment: Ask which part you don't understand and I will try to answer it. But to reactor your code is too much. I already provided sufficient example for you to analyse. Sorry, but if you're asking for someone to do your project, then stack overflow is the wrong place. :)

Comment: in my code in traffic\app\src\main\java\com\app\trafficexam there is a file called PlayQuizActivity.java  you will found function under the name  public void CheckAns()     but it's in if statement if you read it you will get it you are pro in this thing